# Are there any Indian travellers who visited abroad for learning other cultures, faiths?

Tags: history, pilgrimage

Many foreign visitors visited India since ancient times to study the cultures and religions of the land.

Did India have any of its own in the past who similarly travelled across nations to study the different faiths, cultures etc., Is there any written account of Indian travellers describing the world outside India? Are their Journals documenting their travels available?

Answers needed from religious perspective i.e., from Hindu Texts.

Comment: Do you seek answer from mythological side, If yes, this is the right site. If you want it from historical aspect i.e., from recent times, Then [History.stackexchange.com](https://history.stackexchange.com/) would be an appropriate site.

Comment: Religious perspective.

Comment: How much different sites one can join at a time?

Comment: Thank you , will my account on this site expire if i am not able to visit the site for some time.?

Comment: No. It doesn't expire but do try to visit the site regularly and answer the questions asked to you in comments under your questions and answers.  Visit [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help) for more details.

Comment: swami vivekananda has travelled to west and talked about similarities between diffrent cultures and religions

Comment: Paramahansa Yogananda traveled to the United States to understand the hidden teachings of the gospels and later wrote about the similarities between Christianity and Hinduism.

Comment: Is it related to hindu religion at all ?

Comment: I doubt we will find any bcoz, Hinduism has been around forever & Xtianty  & Islam (fr e.g.) came into the picture a couple of 1000 yrs ago. Islam came into being later. As for culture, foreign cultures were mostly underdeveloped at the time. Why would Hindu scholars need to study non-existent or barely existent religions or underdeveloped & poor cultures? The other cultures came to India because there was a weath of knowledge for them to mine and material wealth for the poor countries to plunder and steal. After the country was impoverished by the invasions 1/2

Comment: And the people were brainwashed into believing that other cultures and religions were superior that people started studying them. Religious figures that traveled abroad in the 19th and 20th centuries did so to spread Hindu thought rather than the other way around. 2/2

Answer (score 1):

Guru Nanak Dev ji visited much of central and west Asia in past as a traveler to learn different religions and cultures. Finally he came to present day India to start a new religion called Sikhism, which has the best of teachings/ amalgamation of truths of various religions, documented in a book. later this book was periodically updated by successive Sikh Gurus and the final version is called Guru Granth Sahib, the last eternal guru.

Source and reference - [Guru Granth Sahib](https://archive.org/details/SriGuruGranthSahib-LineByLineDevanagariEnglishTranslation_949)